# Labelling line layer using QgsPalLayerSettings() QGIS failed

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

I'm trying to set label on polygon and line layer using PyQGIS. Setting label on polygon layer succeed, but fails on line layer.

Here my script :

```
        #Set polygon layer
        palyr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
        palyr.readFromLayer(layer_base)
        palyr.enabled = True  # this works
        palyr.fieldName = 'no_urut'  # this works
        palyr.fontSizeInMapUnits = False
        palyr.textFont.setPointSize(6)  # results in 4 - seems to be integer only
        palyr.textColor = QColor(0, 0, 0)  # this works
        palyr.writeToLayer(layer_base)

        #set label line layer
        palyr3 = QgsPalLayerSettings()
        palyr3.readFromLayer(layer_jalan)
        palyr3.enabled = True  # this works
        palyr3.fieldName = 'nama_jalan'  # this works
        palyr3.fontSizeInMapUnits = False
        palyr3.textFont.setPointSize(11)  # results in 4 - seems to be integer only
        palyr3.textColor = QColor(0, 0, 255)  # this works
        palyr3.placementFlags = QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine
        palyr3.writeToLayer(layer_jalan)
```

Any ideas ?, btw when I load it and check on the layer properties, the label has been set according to the properties in the script above and, when I push the apply button on this properties window, the label appears on the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably a mistake in the syntax for QgsPalLayerSettings().

You may try to write this:

```
palyr3.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine
```

instead of:

```
palyr3.placementFlags = QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine
```

Furthermore, you should add this line at the end of the code:

```
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer_base)
```

With these edits, you should use this code (it worked for me):

```
palyr3 = QgsPalLayerSettings()
palyr3.readFromLayer(layer_jalan)
palyr3.enabled = True  # this works
palyr3.fieldName = 'nama_jalan'  # this works
palyr3.fontSizeInMapUnits = False
palyr3.textFont.setPointSize(11)  # results in 4 - seems to be integer only
palyr3.textColor = QColor(0, 0, 255)  # this works
palyr3.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine
palyr3.writeToLayer(layer_jalan)
iface.legendInterface().refreshLayerSymbology(layer_jalan)
```